# Resource leak: 'sc' is never closed in vs code (I'm using the java coding pack from vs code website)

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, redhat-openjdk

Why is vs code giving me a warning on this:
(The warning is below the code)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Input {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string");
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(input);
    }
}
```

The warning is:

> Resource leak: 'sc' is never closed

Answer (score -1):

You can simply put `sc.close()` and this error will no more be displayed. It is not a compulsion. Without this statement also program works fine but if your eyes are getting disturbed by again and again popping u of the message of error then you can put `sc.close()`. Note that after you put it, you can not use `sc` to get input after that statement.
To sort this error:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Input {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string");
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(input);
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) You shouldn't manually close things, but instead use try-with-resources, which guarantees they are closed in the event of an error; 2) there are consequences of closing `sc`: it also closes the underlying stream, which in this case is `System.in`. Closing that means it can't be reopened, which may break other parts of the program which rely on it being open. In general, don't close a stream you didn't open directly (the JVM opened it), but always close streams you did open directly.